# Drawing lines over filled rectangles

Tags: c#, system.drawing

I am trying to draw a 7 x 5 grid on a user control using the following C# code:

```
Pen p = _createPen( Brushes.Red );

int slotWidth = this.Width / 7;
int slotHeight = this.Height / 5;

// columns = days
for ( int c = 1; c < 7; c++ )
{
    // rows = weeks
    for ( int r = 1; r < 5; r++ )
    {
        g.FillRectangle( Brushes.LightGray, new Rectangle( 1, ( ( r - 1 ) * slotHeight ) + 1, this.Width - 2, 10 ) );
        g.DrawLine( p, new Point( 0, r * slotHeight ), new Point( this.Width, r * slotHeight ) );
            }
        g.DrawLine( p, new Point( c * slotWidth, 1 ), new Point( c * slotWidth, this.Height - 2 ) );
    }
}
```

The problem I am having is that the line for the last column is drawing over the filled rectangle, but the others aren't.  I am not sure why as the `FillRectangle()` is done first so that the subsequent `DrawLine()` methods should be drawing over the rectangle, but it's not doing that.

The code has been added to the user control's `Paint()` event.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: I will try to remember that one in future, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Simple place the line:

`g.DrawLine(p, new Point(c * slotWidth, 1), new Point(c * slotWidth, this.Height - 2));`

before the for loop for your rows.

```
  // columns = days
  for (int c = 1; c < 7; c++)
  {
       g.DrawLine(p, new Point(c * slotWidth, 1), new Point(c * slotWidth, this.Height - 2));
       // rows = weeks
       for (int r = 1; r < 5; r++)
       {
            g.FillRectangle(Brushes.LightGray, new Rectangle(1, ((r - 1) * slotHeight) + 1, this.Width - 2, 10));
            g.DrawLine(p, new Point(0, r * slotHeight), new Point(this.Width, r * slotHeight));
       }              
   }
```

The last line is drawing over the others because there comes no next iteration. In the iterations before the last one, you are overpainting every time with the rectangle the red column line.

Comment: I tried it locally and it worked with exact that piece of code. Did you forget something ?

Comment: Tried the same code on a blank form, putting it in the paint event and it worked.  There must be something different about user controls as I was expecting the vertical lines to be drawn over the filled rectangle, but that doesn't appear to happen.  As a workaround I've split out the `FillRectangle` and `DrawLine` methods into separate for loops and it now works.

Comment: I tried it with a Form which i added a UserControl. In the UserControl I overrided the OnPaint and it worked. You must miss there something else :) but i'm glad to hear that it now works